# Getting "The action 'show' could not be found" even though I have defined the method in my config/routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, methods, controller, routes, config

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this in my `config/routes.rb` file

```
resources :my_objects do
  get "import"
end
```

and have defined this in my app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb file

```
def import
  puts "starting"
  service = XACTEService.new(“Stuff”, '2015-06-01', 'Zoo')
  service.process_my_object_data
  puts "finished"
end
```

When I visit http://localhost:3000/my_objects/import, I get this error:

> The action 'show' could not be found for MyObjectsController” error.

I do not see the “puts” statements from my `import` action in the log file.  What else do I need to do to get the `import` method invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `import` route name is being treated like the argument to `show`, because the routes aren't defined properly.  Check the output from `rake routes` to see what it's actually doing in this case.

Instead, you need to define your route like this:

```
resources :my_objects do
  collection do
    get "import"
  end
end
```

or like this:

```
resources :my_objects do
  member do
    get "import"
  end
end
```

The [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide has a section called [Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) that will help you to determine which of these options is right for your app.